ExtJS 6.2: Add afterLabelTextTpl Dynamically
I'm trying to dynamically add an icon after various fields to be used as help (i.g. when the user hovers over the icon a tooltip will appear). I was trying to do this using the afterLabelTextTpl config in a beforerender listener, but I'm not having any luck. Can anyone suggest how I might set afterLabelTextTpl dynamically or another/better method?

This should work with classic toolkit:
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Form',
            bodyPadding: 8,
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Field label',
                listeners: {
                    beforerender: function (field, eOpts) {
                        field.afterLabelTextTpl = [
                            '<tpl>',
                            '<span title="Tooltip" style="cursor: pointer"; class="x-fa fa-user"></span>',
                            '</tpl>'
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});

Setting cursor: pointer is optional but it might be useful. You can add additional styling (padding etc.) in the style part of the span.

Alternative solutions:

You can use a trigger to add info to a textfield (not what you asked for)

Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    
    bodyPadding: 15,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'Display Info Icon With Textfield',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Demo Textfield',

        triggers: {
            info: {
                cls: 'x-fa fa-info',
                tooltip: 'Here is my Info'
            }
        }
    }]
});


Make the config afterLabelTextTpl bindable.

Code
Ext.define('Fiddle.overrides.form.field.Text', {
   override: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
   
   setAfterLabelTextTpl: function(value) {
        const me = this;
        const renderData = me.getLabelableRenderData();

        renderData.afterLabelTextTpl = value;
        if (me.rendered && me.labelEl) {
            labelHtml = this.labelableRenderTpl.apply(renderData)

            me.labelEl.setHtml(labelHtml);
        }
    }
});

Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    
    viewModel: {
        data: {
            tooltip: 'This is lazy.'
        }
    },

    bodyPadding: 15,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'Display Info Icon With Textfield',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Demo Textfield',
        labelWidth: 120,
        bind: {
            afterLabelTextTpl: '<span class="cool-info" data-qtip="{tooltip}"></span>'
        }

    }]
});

style
.cool-info {
    position: relative;
}
.cool-info:after {
    content: 'i';
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px grey;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
}

.x-form-item-label {
    overflow: visible;
}

Link to Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3sd4
